# Removendo elementos duplicados em uma lista com python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tenho que fazer uma função e não estou conseguindo desenvolver a lógica. É o seguinte:

> Escreva a função remove_repetidos que recebe como parâmetro uma lista com números inteiros, verifica se tal lista possui elementos repetidos e os remove. A função deve devolver uma lista correspondente à primeira lista, sem elementos repetidos. A lista devolvida deve estar ordenada.

Dica: Você pode usar `lista.sort()` ou `sorted(lista)`.

Comment: amigo esse era um desafio da USP em Python correto? tente se esforçar mais e fazer perguntas referente ao seu código...não pedir respostas

Comment: Essa pergunta é constantemente  feita na comunidade, até uma simples busca no google retornaria posts relacionados com tudo espero que tenha entendido sobre o conteúdo e antes de refazer a pergunta poderia ter pesquisado sobre no campo chamado "PESQUISA"  logo acima.

Answer (score 10):

Uma função *pythonica* para resolver este problema seria:

```
def remove_repetidos(lista):
    l = []
    for i in lista:
        if i not in l:
            l.append(i)
    l.sort()
    return l

lista = [1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 3, 6, 7, 6, 7, 8, 10 ,9]

lista = remove_repetidos(lista)
print (lista)
```

Saída:

```
>>>[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

É bem fácil perceber como a função funciona, por isso vou omitir mais explicações.

Comment: Me deparei com esse desafio da USP hoje e não tava conseguindo fazer, obrigado. Eu estava tentando usar o `del` pra deletar os elementos repetidos da lista, mas isso bagunçava os índices, fazendo com que o `for` não funcionasse corretamente.

Comment: Outra resposta tem uma versão realmente "pythonica", simplesmente usar `sorted(set(lista))`. É mais limpo, mais fácil de entender e mais rápido.
Esta resposta funciona bem, só estou deixando este comentário pois a resposta está bem votada e pode criar uma visão errada do que é considerado "pythonico" pela comunidade.

Answer (score 8):

A lista deve estar ordenada, porém na mesma ordem da original ou pode-se ordenar depois?

Digo isso pois `set()` é usado justamente pra isso e é bastante eficiente inclusive.
De forma geral você deve evitar de reprogramar aquilo que já está na biblioteca padrão.

```
>>> lista = [1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 3, 6, 7, 6, 7, 8, 10 ,9]
>>> sorted(set(lista))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Já se você necessita manter a mesma ordem da lista original veja essa resposta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-in-whilst-preserving-order

Ou então crie um [OrderedSet](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576694/) que seria o equivalente a um collections.OrderedDict só que para listas. Funciona bem também.

Answer (score 4):

## TL;DR

Se a **ordem original** da lista **NÃO importa**:

```
def remove_dups(lista):
    """Remove os itens duplicados mas não mantém a ordem original."""
    return list(set(lista))
```

Se a **ordem original** da lista **importa** (Python3.7+)

```
# CPython3.6+
# Pypy 2.7+
# Outras implementações Python3.7+
def remove_dups(lista):
    """Remove os itens duplicados mantendo a ordem original."""
    return list(dict.fromkeys(lista))
```

Se a **ordem original** da lista **importa** (Versões mais antigas do Python)

```
from collections import OrderedDict

# Versões anteriores do Python
def remove_dups(lista):
    """Remove os itens duplicados mantendo a ordem original."""
    return list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(lista))
```

---

### Mantendo a ordem da lista original

Como não vi postarem aqui ainda, depois que a linguagem começou a garantir a ordem de inserção nas chaves do `dict` (ver [notas de versão do Python 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html#summary-release-highlights)), você pode usar o método [`dict.fromkeys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys) para criar um dicionário recebendo apenas um iterável com as chaves (ou seja, sem [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)). E depois basta converter de volta para lista.

Demonstração:

```
lista = [1, 2, 10, 4, 5, 1, 1]

dict_aux = dict.fromkeys(lista)
# {1: None, 2: None, 10: None, 4: None, 5: None}

resultado = list(dict_aux)
# [1, 2, 10, 4, 5]
```

PS: Lembrando que esse comportamento já existe na implementação do CPython 3.6.

---

### Ignorando a ordem da lista original

Já se você não se importa com a ordem basta converter para um set e depois para uma lista novamente, como já mencionado em outras respostas.

```
lista = [1, 2, 10, 4, 5, 1, 1]

set_aux = set(lista)
# {1, 2, 4, 5, 10}

resultado = list(set_aux)
# [1, 2, 4, 5, 10]
```

---

### Performance

A motivação desta sessão foi [esse tweet](https://twitter.com/raymondh/status/944125570534621185) do Raymond Hettinger (um dos *core developers* do CPython), onde ele afirma que a maneira mais rápida de remover itens duplicados mantendo a ordem da lista original é usando [`dict.fromkeys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys).

Então estou testando os seguintes algoritmos:

1. Usando `set` mas perdendo a ordem da lista original (para comparar com as outras soluções):

   ```
   def remove_dups_set(lista):
       return list(set(lista))
   ```
2. Usando `dict.fromkeys`:

   ```
   def remove_dups_fromkeys(lista):
       return list(dict.fromkeys(lista))
   ```
3. Usando `OrderedDict` como já proposto em outra resposta:

   ```
   def remove_dups_ordered_dict(lista):
       return list(OrderedDict((v, None) for v in lista))
   ```
4. Alterando a versão anterior para usar o método `OrderedDict.fromkeys`:

   ```
   def remove_dups_fromkeys_ordered_dict(lista):
       return list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(lista))
   ```
5. Usando um `for` normalmente como mencionado em outra resposta:

   ```
   def remove_dups_for(lista):
       l = []
       for i in lista:
           if i not in l:
               l.append(i)
       return l
   ```
6. Alterando a versão anterior para que use um `set` checar se o valor já está na lista ou não:

   ```
   def remove_dups_for_and_set(lista):
       l = []
       visited = set()  # guarda os itens que já estão em `l`
       for i in lista:
           if i not in visited:  # sets são otimizados para operações do tipo "in"
               l.append(i)
               visited.add(i)
       return l
   ```

#### Resultados

Resultados obtidos neste [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@fernandosavio/SOPt-529209-6333) usando o módulo [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) para medir o tempo de execução:

```
                  remove_dups_set:  1.2999 s
             remove_dups_fromkeys:  2.7048 s
         remove_dups_ordered_dict: 25.0388 s
remove_dups_fromkeys_ordered_dict:  5.4657 s
                  remove_dups_for:  7.6752 s
          remove_dups_for_and_set:  5.2055 s
```

*PS: a máquina que roda o Repl.it não é muito forte, se você for executar os testes na sua máquina seria legal aumentar o número de iterações para um número maior (no Repl.it está `number=100_000`). E também aumentar o tamanho da lista para que se torne mais evidente a diferença das soluções de acordo com o tamanho da lista (no Repl.it está `* 50`).*

Answer (score 1):

Outra forma interessante para resolver esta questão é utilizar o método **[OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)** da biblioteca **[collections](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html)**. Neste caso podemos montar o seguinte código:

```
from collections import OrderedDict


def remove_repetidos(li):
    return sorted(OrderedDict((i, None) for i in li))


lista = [1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 3, 6, 7, 6, 7, 8, 10, 9]

print(remove_repetidos(lista))
```

O resultado deste algoritmo é:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Podemos obter o mesmo resultado utilizando a **expressão lambda** associada com a função **map()**, tal como listado no código abaixo:

```
lista = [1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 3, 6, 7, 6, 7, 8, 10, 9]
unicos = sorted(map(lambda x: x[1], filter(lambda x: x[1] not in
                lista[:x[0]], enumerate(lista))))

print(unicos)
```

Com este algoritmo obtemos o mesmo resultado que é:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

---

Outra forma interessante é utilizar o seguinte algoritmo:

```
def remove_repetidos(li):
    return sorted(dict(zip(li, li)).keys())


lista = [1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 3, 6, 7, 6, 7, 8, 10, 9]

print(remove_repetidos(lista))
```

Obtendo desta forma o mesmo resultado:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

---

Outra forma válida de responder esta questão pode ser:

```
lista = [1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 3, 6, 7, 6, 7, 8, 10, 9]
r = []
[r.append(i) for i in lista if not r.count(i)]

print(sorted(r))
```

Resultando na seguinte saída:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

Acho que dá pra fazer utilizando a função del, da seguinte forma:

````
def remove_repetidos(l):

    lista = l
    i = 0
    while i < len(lista):
        j = i + 1
        while j < len(lista):
            if lista[j] == lista[i]:
                del(lista[j])
            else:
                j = j + 1
        i = i + 1

    return sorted(lista)```
````

Answer (score 0):

tive problemas utilizando `lista.sort()` ou `sorted(lista)`, (se for uma lista txt, é colocado um "\n" toda vez que apertamos "enter", então fiz de outra forma)

Código:

```
def tira_nome(lista):
    listaP = []
    num = 0
    for lis in lista:
        lis = lis.rstrip()
        for letter in listaP:  
            if letter == lis:
                num = 1
        if num == 0:
            listaP.append(lis)
            num = 0
        else:
            num = 0
    return listaP
```

Answer (score -2):

```
numeros = input("Digite uma lista com números inteiros: ")


print("Você digitou os seguintes números: ")
print(numeros)

#Cria a função remove_repetidos que cria e ordena um set a #partir de uma lista
remove_repetidos = lambda l: list(sorted(set(l)))

'''remove_repetidos.remove(" ")'''

print("Sua lista filtrada e ordenada: ")
print(remove_repetidos(numeros))
```

Answer (score -3):

new_df = list(set(self.df['col']))

Comment: Poderia explica melhor sua resposta?