# Função para tirar duplicação de uma lista de lista- Python

Tags: python, funções, lista

Pessoal eu tenho essa lista:

```
lista = [['10616558', 0],
 ['2856466', 1],
 ['9715350', 2],
 ['9715350', 3],
 ['9715350', 4],
 ['10720706', 5]]
```

O primeiro elemento é uma string qualquer, e o segundo é um índice. Preciso fazer uma função que tire os elementos da lista que contém a mesma string, preservando o índice.

O *output* seria dessa forma:

```
>>> lista = removeigual(lista)
>>> lista
[['10616558', 0],
 ['2856466', 1],
 ['9715350', 2],
 ['10720706', 5]]
```

Eu tenho uma função que remove duplicações mas é somente para listas simples, mas não consegui adaptar para meu problema:

```
def removeDuplicates(listofElements):

    uniqueList = []

    for elem in listofElements:
        if elem not in uniqueList:
            uniqueList.append(elem)
    return uniqueList
```

Comment: Deve ser preservado o índice da primeira ocorrência do valor?

Comment: Essa pergunta é respondida [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/192567/removendo-elementos-duplicados-em-uma-lista-com-python).

Comment: Oi Anderson. Sim eu preciso preservar os índices!

Comment: @TryAgain, a função do problema citado funciona apenas para listas simples. Quando eu jogo a minha lista. Ele me retorna a mesma coisa, por causa dos índices. Ele ve o indice e ver que é um valor diferente, e não retira nada, mesmo com a string tendo o mesmo valor. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu código está quase adaptado ao seu problema, apenas foram feitas umas pequenas alterações na linha `if elem not in uniqueList:`.

É percorrida toda a lista inicial e, quando é encontrado um valor com uma string que já foi utilizada, esta não é adicionada à lista final:

```py
def removeDuplicates(listofElements):
  uniqueList = []
  for elem in listofElements:
    if elem[0] not in [i[0] for i in uniqueList]:  # se string ainda não estiver na uniqueList
      uniqueList.append(elem)
  return uniqueList

lista = [['10616558', 0],
         ['2856466', 1],
         ['9715350', 2],
         ['9715350', 3],
         ['9715350', 4],
         ['10720706', 5]]

print(removeDuplicates(lista))
```

Output:

```
[['10616558', 0], ['2856466', 1], ['9715350', 2], ['10720706', 5]]
```

Comment: Obrigado t3m2! Sua solução deu certo também valeeeeu ! :D

Answer (score 0):

A solução a seguir funciona caso o index seja um valor fixo e não um número proveniente de alguma função sendo executada dentro da lista.

```
lista = [['banana',0], ['caju',1], ['banana',2]]

for fruta in lista:
    for checkduplicada in lista:
        if fruta[0] == checkduplicada[0] and fruta[1] != checkduplicada[1]:
            lista.remove(checkduplicada)

print(lista)

output = [['banana', 0], ['caju', 1]]
```

Veja se é possível aplicar ao seu caso.

Comment: Oi Felipe. Obrigado pela resposta. Consegui a solução mas a sua também me ajudou a compreender a resposta :D

Answer (score 0):

Se puder (e não vejo porque não poderia) utilizar geradores, você pode, ao invés de armazenar a lista inteira, com *string* e índice, para controlar quais já foram retornadas, armazenar apenas a *string* que é o seu referencial. A lógica basicamente é que para cada item da sua lista de entrada, você verifica se a *string* já foi retornada e, se não, retorna o *array* com *string* e índice; se já foi retornado basta ignorar.

```py
def remove_duplicates(sequences):
    returned = []
    for sequence in sequences:
        if sequence[0] not in returned:
            yield sequence
            returned.append(sequence[0])
```

Assim, basta fazer:

```py
nao_repetidos = list(remove_duplicates(lista))
```

Como o retorno da função é um gerador, basta utilizar `list()` para obter como uma lista.

Algumas otimizações podem ser feitas, tal como fazer `returned`, que é uma lista, ser um conjunto (`set`), melhorando a busca dos elementos; e se a lista de entrada já estiver classificada quanto à *string*, você não precisa manter em memória todas as *strings* retornadas, basta verificar se a atual dentro do laço de repetição é igual à última *string* retornada pela função.

Uma solução sem geradores poderia ser, supondo uma lista de entrada classificada quanto à *string*:

```py
def remove_duplicates(sequences):
    last_string = None
    result = []
    for sequence in sequences:
        if sequence[0] != last_string:
            result.append(sequence)
            last_string = sequence[0]
    return result
```

Que é uma solução particularmente interessante por ser O(n), percorrendo a lista apenas uma vez e sem depender de buscas em listas intermediárias.

Comment: Obrigado pelo resposta Anderson. Eu preciso do índice pq eu vou buscar o indice em uma outra lista de mesmo tamanho e ordenação de outra fonte. Mas eu nao podia usar essa deduplicação na outra lista. Então tive essa ideia de deduplicar a minha lista q poderia ser deduplicada, atribuindo um índice, e depois da deduplicação eu pego esse índice e puxo as infos da outra lista. O seu segundo código funcionou perfeitamente na minha amostra. Muito Obrigado :D